# Unable to decipher SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I consider myself fairly experienced in writing SQL statements, but by no means an expert. I'm having to work with a statement someone else created and can't quite follow what they did can anyone help me understand? It might just be over my head:

```
...
from
    (
        select
            2000+(t*10+u) as `year`
        from
        (select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
        (select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B
        where
            (2000+(t*10+u)) >= @minYear
            and (2000+(t*10+u)) <= @maxYear
    ) innerSelect
...
```

the `@maxYear` and `@minYear` I can follow but the `2000+(t*10+u)` and `select 0 u union select 1...` is what's confusing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just one of the many tricks to generate a table of sequential numbers. In this case from minYear to maxYear as long as they are beyond the year 2000.

See http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

section: Generating a sequence of 1,000 numbers

It's probably easier to understand if you consider that the following

```
select t,u 
from
(select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A,
(select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B
```

generates all the combinations between the numbers 0 to 9:

```
0,0
0,1
0,2
...
1,0
1,1
1,2
...
...
9,9
```

so now you should be able to understand that `select 2000+(t*10+u)` 
will generate

```
2000
2001
2002
...
2099
```

The `WHERE` clause just limits the years to those from `minYear` to `maxYear`

Answer (score 6):

They're just generating a list of years from `@minYear` to `@maxYear`. Given a "tens digit" of t and a "ones digit" of u you can get the year with 2000 + 10*t + u. So, for 2016 tens would be 1 and ones would be 6.

Comment: your answer was correct as well but I selected the other one since it broke things down. Gave you an up vote for the help. :D